# Firebird constant value

Tags: firebird

Is it possible to have database wide constants?
What I want is to define a constant like:

- UPDATE_CONSTANT = 1
- INSERT_CONSTANT = 2
- DELETE_CONSTANT = 3

and then use it  in for example a trigger like:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER AD_PRJ_PROJECTS FOR PRJ_PROJECT
ACTIVE AFTER DELETE
POSITION 1
AS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE SP_ADD_HISTORY 'PRJ_PROJECT', DELETE_CONSTANT;
END;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you intend to do with the constant

Comment: I want a named constant that I can use anywhere y the database: procedure, triggers, etc. Like a Domain but with a value

Comment: @Daniel: You haven't answered my question.

Comment: I think he wan't to use constants to make the code more readabel.

Comment: The delphi tag is not relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a generator:

```sql
SET GENERATOR DELETE_CONSTANT TO 3;

...

EXECUTE PROCEDURE SP_ADD_HISTORY 'PRJ_PROJECT', GEN_ID(DELETE_CONSTANT, 0);
```

---

**Update**: yes, using a generator for this purpose is dangerous, as they can be changed. 
However, in FireBird 3.0 Alpha 1 this risk can be eliminated using access rights: [**Grants access on generators**](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-2553).

Comment: I'll accept this answer, however using generators and calling them with GEN_ID() defeat the pourpose of the "constant" idea of been easier the read/use/maintain.
The correct answer should be: It's not possible to get it straightforward.

Comment: thanks :-) ... another solution could be a UDF with the name DELETE_CONSTANT() which returns the constant value ... this is no perfect answer either ;) ...

Comment: Generators are not constants. Do not use them as such. If for any one reason this generator is modified you can have a whole bunch of code which suddenly throws out incorrect answers. It might be a long time before you find the problem.

Comment: That's terrible practice and very error prone. Generator is not a constant and it could be changed!

Comment: generators sometimes change even when no code changing them even present. maybe by backup/restore, or some db repairing, no one will know. but they can. See my comment below BennyBechDk answer. So FB3 grants would not save you from that. And after DB would became a mess, "it could not happen" would sound silly. Are you ready to check that generators not changed on every connection to DB or maybe even each statement ?

Comment: @Arioch'The this sounds like a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug) - maybe alpha particles or cosmic rays :D

Comment: No it is not :-) Heisenbug is recurring on unknown condition. Thay was a one-time lapse. If you split sequences by that mid-2008 borderline, then you have two strictly monotone increasing sequences. They just dropped the value one unlucky day.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an easy way for declaring constants.

I could be done by creating you own DLL for user defined function, and lmake a function for each constant.

I Think the Idea using generators as "global" constants is briliant.

But you can make a "local constant" to make your code a bit more readable:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER AD_PRJ_PROJECTS FOR PRJ_PROJECT
ACTIVE AFTER DELETE
POSITION 1
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE DELETE_CONSTANT INTEGER;
BEGIN
   DELETE_CONSTANT = 1;
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE SP_ADD_HISTORY 'PRJ_PROJECT', DELETE_CONSTANT;
END;
```

Comment: In lates release you can write:

 DECLARE VARIABLE DELETE_CONSTANT INTEGER = 1;

Comment: It is from Firebird 1.5 that variabeles can be initialized

Comment: that's same issue as with generators. variables CAN be accidetalyl changed, and then it all goes wrong, and if u used to think of it as true constant you would never check their true value and never find why it all suddenly messed up.

Comment: what about generators, our legacy app has a logging table (yes, it is probably bad idea transaction-wise, but it was done). One of actions logged is login/logout. PK is integer, inserted by trigger from generator. No single place in DB or in application those trigger and generator are used. So nothing can go worng, true ? But they called for support lcaiming they cannot log in. They sent DB and... that log table ordered by PK looks like a mess: 10-40 records of 2005-2008/1, 10-40 records of 2008/2-2012, 1-20 used PK values, again 2005-2008/1 lined, again later lines, again early lines,... etc

Comment: so frankly, they suffer from login problems since mid-2008 ! They used to click time and again until generator would increment to the next unused spot. Sardonic think, when they called as - the generator was pointing to last line of yet another used segment, so one attempt more and they would log in again...  for a while. I n't know what happened in mid-2008 and how they zeroed that generator, but they did! And who knows what other generators as well. When i glared upion all that i only could think "impossible. DB in that state and in-production and almost working..." DON'T rely on gens values

Answer (score 0):

You can implement some simple preprocesor of yours scripts that converts constants to values..

triggers.presql

```sql
@DELETE_CONSTANT = 1
CREATE TRIGGER AD_PRJ_PROJECTS FOR PRJ_PROJECT
ACTIVE AFTER DELETE
POSITION 1
BEGIN
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE SP_ADD_HISTORY 'PRJ_PROJECT', DELETE_CONSTANT;
END;
```

triggers.sql

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER AD_PRJ_PROJECTS FOR PRJ_PROJECT
ACTIVE AFTER DELETE
POSITION 1
BEGIN
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE SP_ADD_HISTORY 'PRJ_PROJECT', 1;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a single row table with triggers that prevent insertion and deletion from it. Having to read from it certainly does not makes code clearer but it helps to implement such "constants". Also remove write permissions from everybody but sysdba